# Configure DHCP role on windows server without starting it

Tags: dhcp, windows

we want to migrate our dhcp service from a linux server to a windows 2008 r2 server. We have a huge list of mac-ip static leases. Is it possible to install a dhcp role on the windows server and configure it *without* actually starting the server s.t. a 'hot swap' of dhcp servers is possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Just keep your DHCP range deactivated. The DHCP server doesn't distribute ip addresses then.

Also, it might be worth trying to google for a config file migration. A long time ago I also migrated a DHCP server from Win 2003 to Win 2008 and I remember that there are command line tools to export the config and static leases to a text like file and import it then via powershell in windows 2008. I don't remember exactly how I did it, but just try to google it.
If you don't find anything just let me know, then I'll look it up on an old Win2003 server

Comment: Well I need to transfer a dhcpd.conf to windows, so I need some script to process the dhcpd.conf

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overread the "from a linux server". Well, then it's probably easier to create the entries by hand, or you could try to export the config from the new win 2008 DHCP server and try to reproduce the config file patterns from the reservations lines with a script.